# Connection to external postgres database times out

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to connect a client device to a PostGreSQL host device. I have 2 devices with PostGreSQL on them: A Windows OS device (Host) and a RaspberryPi running raspbian (Client).

I have pgAdmin on the host device, with a PostGreSQL server running on it (The server is the default PostGreSQL server with default configurations).
**The host device and the client device are on the same network (wifi).**

---

I have the following node.js code on the client device:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:MyPassword@192.168.1.8:5433/postgres';
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString
});
client.connect();
client.query('CREATE TABLE test (something text, number int)', function(err,result){
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(result);
   console.log('hi');
});
```

based on the code above, the client would connect and query the making of a table, then return the result and 'hi' in the command line.

When I run it, it does nothing. After a minute or so, the connection times out.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

---

I used Wireshark to see if the client device was even sending packets. The client device was sending packets (directed to the postgresql post), so my assumption is that the problem is with the host device, but I don't know why because I have already edited the configuration files multiple times by now.

I have already...

- changed config files
- restarted the system
- re-installed the software
- switched to trying to connect from psql

---

Well, this is interesting...

So I found the real .config files on the host device, and I changed `listen_addresses = '*'` to `listen_addresses = '192.168.1.12'`. 
After I made those changes, I tried to restart postgres and then the service stopped, but refused to be started again. I opened pgAdmin 4, and none of the servers were wanting to connect. After I changed the file back to `listen_addresses = '*'` the service started and everything was back to normal. My conclusion now is that there is a problem with the firewall. Does anyone here do Windows and can help me configure the firewall??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was bothering myself with the Postgres configuration files, but I had to look at the firewall configurations. Those were the ones that were blocking the pi. If anyone has the same problem, I suggest looking at your firewall first. (Specifically allowing port 5432)

Comment: From the client machine, just attempt to connect via tcp/5432 (or whatever port you have postgres listening on). `Test-NetConnection` on Windows or `nc -vz <address> <port>` on Linux. If that fails, then check your network gear.